# How to fill in columns tied to carrierWave without going through carrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

In developing a Ruby on Rails application, when I pass a file object to a column in a model with a CarrierWave set, it will correctly populate that column as well as save it to storage.
However, the file I want to upload to storage already exists on the storage, so how can I make the column with the CarrierWave set to correctly populate the string?

The case we are envisioning is when you can copy a file on S3 so that you don't have to download the file locally to pass it through CarrierWave.

However, I am wondering if the only way to do this is to download the file object, since it is not reflected purely by putting a string in that column.

Comment: It's a little tricky, but it can be done. The store_dir on the Uploader class you use to mount the document on the model and the file name stored in the column are used by carrierwave to determine where the file is stored.